# LiveSuit (or other similar tools) for Linux or BSD

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, usb-drivers, stock-rom

I need to Flash a new ROM on to a `Allwinner A13 tablet`. But I have no access to a windows Box.
Is there any tools like LiveSuit for Linux or BSD.
Also if/how to install tablet device driver.

Comment: There's [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk) which `adb` and `fastboot` is sufficient. As for BSD, there's very little support for the BSD un*x systems in regards to flashing and all associated with Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some projects that have gotten LiveSuit to work on Linux, such as [this website](http://linux-sunxi.org/LiveSuit) and details in [this forum](http://www.cubieforums.com/index.php?topic=317.0).

Most of what I could find focused on A10 chipsets, but A13 is close enough that it might work (of course, you'll have to find A13 specific ROMs). The second link also shows how to manually install drivers. Since you didn't specify your exact model, you may have to modify the directions somewhat to work with your device.

The easiest solution, of course, is to get access to a Windows box. A year ago, Linux support wasn't so good, so I had to borrow someone's computer for a bit to flash my Allwinner A13 tablet. Even more restrictive is the ability to generate your own ROM images. I couldn't find anything that would work on Linux, so I was stuck using Windows to [upgrade my tablet](https://www.schrauger.com/how-to-upgrade-a-trio-stealth-7-model-7c-a13-from-ics-to-jb)* to Android 4.1.

*I wrote this post.

Comment: Mine is JXD-S9100 but currently running Freelander PD60. (PS:Do you know any 4.1 Firmware for it). I also got the `CWM` working on it. Could i put the `.img` ROM file on the SD card and flash it that way instead of `LiveSuit`?